# What is the typical way of going about monitor resolution when making a full screen GUI?

Tags: user-interface, monitor

I'm making a program that will have a widget that has to be fixed in size, is there an industry standard for smallest resolution width?

What are some common way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: What kind of a program? Targeting what kind of audience? On what kind of platform / device?

Comment: Science/Educational, students, Windows XP and up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On traditional PCs (i.e. no mobile, no "custom", no specialized hardware) You usually will not find a display with a resultion below 640x800x256, so that is the "technical" de-facto standard.

However, if you try to design for that resolution, your controls will look ugly and uneconomically designed, wasting lots of available space on real-world platforms.

I'd say 800x600x16 is an absolute minimum requirement. Even windows save mode usually is able to come up with (or can be switched to) 800x600. So I usually design resizeable apps for 800x600, and if done right, they look and behave great under even the largest resolutions. In contrast, if you design a resizeable app for 640x480, you will make an awful lot of compromises in layouting etc. due to the limited space available, and that while "nobody" uses that resolution in the real world.

Furthermore, I love applications that resize intelligently. Depending on your GUI framework/toolkit, that is a requirement that you can be met easily, or not-so-easily. It's worth the hassle, though.

You might also consider the font scaling setting. On large-resolution displays, many users prefer the "large fonts" setting, or something else different from the original font scaling setting. Then, your app must scale accordingly, and the minimum resolution criterium gets less important, while the apps's ability to re-size intelligently gains much more significance.

In short: 
a) Design for 800x600x16
a.1) Let your app terminate with an error message if the resolution is smaller than that
b) Make sure all resizeable dialogs resize intelligently
c) Test all layouts on large and small font scaling settings as well
d) When saying "800x600", this is useless, since your app usually cannot use the whole screen, even if maximized. (We are not talking about fullscreen apps, do we?) So you should account for the task bar and possibly other fixed screen elements that cannot be used by a normal Window, and for the window's title bar when maximized. You will want the window to fit into the desktop area in all cases. (Well, maybe you will.) Windows can tell you the dimensions of that area, taking account all task bar etc. stuff that the user might happen to use, so you could alert/abort if the usable space is smaller than your minimum resolution that you designed for.

Answer (score 1):

For PCs (excluding embedded stuff like handphones, wristwatches, mp3 players, washing machines etc..) the smallest resolution is 640x480 otherwise known as VGA resolution.

There may be some PC-class computers like early [Macs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh), [Ataris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari) or [TRS-80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80)s with smaller resolutions but nobody uses them nowdays. Conventional wisdom says the smallest monitor width is 640 pixels wide.

In the last 10 years a lot of developers have upped the assumed minimum resolution to 1024x768 otherwise known as XGA (btw, nobody calls them VGA or XGA anymore since the mid 1990s). All graphics card manufactured since 1999 can handle at least 1024 pixels as the minimum width.

768 pixels used to be assumed as the minimum height by a lot of developers in the last 10 years until 3 years ago when Asus invented the Netbook category. Most netbooks have a resolution of 1024x600. So a lot of software cannot fit on netbook screens (much to the annoyance of netbook owners).

Currently (since I'm one of those netbook owners) my own standard minimum is 1024x600, that is, 1024 pixels wide vs 600 pixels high (actually more like 560 pixels because I usually have to account for the menubar and the taskbar).

Note: wikipedia has a nice summary of standard monitor resolutions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_display_resolutions